# Counter in for loop not reseting despite if statement

Tags: java

```
public class Diabetes {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double T = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    double deltat = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
    int n = StdIn.readInt();
    int i = 1;
    double r = StdIn.readDouble();
    double[] positionX = new double[n];
    double[] positionY = new double[n];
    double[] velocityX = new double[n];
    double[] velocityY = new double[n];
    double[] mass = new double[n];
    String[] image = new String[n];


    double[] deltaX = new double[n * n];
    double[] deltaY = new double[n * n];
    double[] radius = new double[n * n];
    double[] force = new double[n * n * n];
    double g = 6.67E-11;
    double[] forceX = new double[n * n];
    double[] forceY = new double[n * n];               
    double[] cosine = new double[n * n];
    double[] sine = new double[n * n];
    double[] accelerationX = new double[n * n];
    double[] accelerationY = new double[n * n];
    double[] newvelocityX = new double[n * n];
    double[] newvelocityY = new double[n * n];
    double[] newpositionX = new double[n * n];
    double[] newpositionY = new double[n * n];

    int positionX_counter = 0;
    int positionY_counter = 0;
    int velocityX_counter = 0;
    int velocityY_counter = 0;
    int mass_counter = 0;
    int image_counter=0;
    //System.out.println("n = " + n + "r = " + r);

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for(int k = 1; k < 7; k++)
            if (k == 6) {
            image[image_counter] = StdIn.readString();
            System.out.println(image[image_counter]);
            image_counter++;
            //System.out.println("image counter = " + image_counter);
            }
            else if (k == 5) {
            mass[mass_counter] = Double.parseDouble(StdIn.readString());
            System.out.println(mass[mass_counter]);
            mass_counter++;
            //System.out.println("masscounter = " + mass_counter);
            }
            else if (k == 4) {
            velocityY[velocityY_counter] = Double.parseDouble(StdIn.readString());
            System.out.println(velocityY[velocityY_counter]);
            velocityY_counter++;
            //System.out.println("velcounter = " + velocity_counter);
            }
            else if (k == 3) {
            velocityX[velocityX_counter] = Double.parseDouble(StdIn.readString());
            System.out.println(velocityX[velocityX_counter]);
            velocityX_counter++;
            //System.out.println("velcounter = " + velocity_counter);
            }
            else if (k == 2) {
            positionY[positionY_counter] = Double.parseDouble(StdIn.readString());
            System.out.println(positionY[positionY_counter]);
            positionY_counter++;
            }
            else if (k == 1) {
            positionX[positionX_counter] = Double.parseDouble(StdIn.readString());
            System.out.println(positionX[positionX_counter]);
            positionX_counter++;
            }
        }
        for (int m = 0; m <= 10; m++) {
            if ( i == 5 ) { 
                i = 1;
            }
            else {
                    deltaX[m] = positionX[i] - positionX[m];
                    deltaY[m] = positionY[i] - positionY[m];
                    radius[m] = Math.sqrt((deltaX[i] * deltaX[i]) + (deltaY[i] * deltaY[i]));
                    force[m] = (g * mass[m] * mass[i]) / (radius[m] * radius[m]);
                    cosine[m] = (deltaX[m] / radius[m]);
                    sine[m] = (deltaY[m] / radius[m]);
                    forceX[m] = force[m] * cosine[m];
                    forceY[m] = force[m] * sine[m];
                    accelerationX[m] = forceX[m] / mass[i];
                    accelerationY[m] = forceY[m] / mass[i];
                    newvelocityX[m] = velocityX[i] + (deltat*accelerationX[m]);
                    newvelocityY[m] = velocityY[i] + (deltat*accelerationY[m]);
                    newpositionX[m] = positionX[i] + (deltat*velocityX[i]);
                    //System.out.println(newpositionX[m]);
                    newpositionY[m] = positionY[i] + (deltat*velocityY[i]);
                    i++;
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

Hey Guys, really confused by this code I've written and why it's throwing an error. Essentially I have some arrays of length (5) and I'm trying to do some calculations with them and store those in an array of length 10. So the code is designed to do ten calculations with five number arrays, so naturally I designed it to have two different counters within the for loop. The first one *should* reset when it reaches 5, and the other one kills the loop when it hits 10. What doesn't make any sense at all is that the program is spitting out the output that i=5, but it's not going into the if statement and reseting itself so I get thrown an error about my array being out of bounds.

Thanks for any help

Comment: well where is the error being thrown from in this wall of text?  What debugging have you done?

Comment: Also it looks like the value of `i` should be `0` not `1`

Comment: The error is being thrown at line 96. Sorry I should have explained that. The only debugging that I've down is having it print out what "i" is and it's telling me it's 5 but not going in the if statement

Comment: so simplify you are saying that this code `int i = 1;
  for (int m = 0; m <= 10; m++) {
            if ( i == 5 ) { 
                i = 1;
            }
            else {
                    i++;
                    System.out.println(i);
            }
         }` does not work?  Try re-compiling

Comment: Shouldn't the terminating condition in for statement be m<10 instead of m<= 10, given that the length of all arrays is 10?

Comment: If I delete all the calculations before the System.out.println(i) then it works. But with it there, it doesn't work.

Comment: so you have a simple OOB problem - probably because of the value of `m` not `i`

Comment: I switched from m <= 10 to m < 10 but see no difference. Which makes logical sense

Comment: without even showing the error, there is not much help that can be offered